# Truncate partition doesn't throw an error when the partition range is lower than base partition oracle

Tags: database, oracle, truncate, database-partitioning

I have a table partitioned based on the year and month (eg:202001).
Let's say the oldest data available is for partition **201304** and the latest available is for 202001.What I observed was when we attempt to truncate partition for **202103** I get the partition does not exist error, which is expected

ORA-02149: Specified partition does not exist

But when I try to truncate a partition older than the oldest one say **201010**,it doesn't throw any errors. Oracle simply mentions Partition truncated even though the partition doesn't exist. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please post the partition definition. I presume you use range partitioning (as the most common case for dates), which has upper boundary (`values less than (<value>)`), but no lower boundary

Answer (score 4):

You have to realise thet the Oracle *range* partitions are defined on the condition `less than` not on a fixed schema e.g. *month of data*.

So the first partition has *no lower bound* and you observe therefore an expected behavior as illustrated on the example below
(assuming somehow your partitioning schema, but would not recomend to do it in this way -> using  `DATE` column and *interval* partitioning would be prefered)

```
create table tab (
id int,
yyyymm varchar2(6)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (yyyymm)
(
partition p201304 VALUES LESS THAN ('201305'),
partition p201305 VALUES LESS THAN ('201306'),
partition p201306 VALUES LESS THAN ('201307')
);



alter table tab drop partition for ('201309');
-- ORA-14702: The partition number is invalid or out-of-range

alter table tab drop partition for ('201305');
-- Table TAB altered. p201305 was dropped

alter table tab drop partition for ('201001');
-- Table TAB altered. partition P201304 was dropped
```